# Why is my custom display template not selected in my provisioned page?

Tags: display-template

I created custom display templates (control and item). I provision also a new page. This page is using my custom pagelayout with some webpart zones. I add some webparts inside this webpartzones by the page provisioning. One of these webparts is a searchbycontentwebpart. I try to select my custom display templates, but it is still using the default display templates. What do I missing?

When I try to select the custom display templates manualy from the GUI it is working.

```
    <AllUsersWebPart WebPartOrder ="3" WebPartZoneID ="wpzSearchResult">
            <![CDATA[        
              <webParts>
  <webPart xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebPart/v3">
    <metaData>
      <type name="Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.WebControls.ContentBySearchWebPart, Microsoft.Office.Server.Search, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" />
      <importErrorMessage>Kan dit webonderdeel niet importeren.</importErrorMessage>
    </metaData>
    <data>
      <properties>
        <property name="StatesJson" type="string">{}</property>
        <property name="UseSharedDataProvider" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="UseSimplifiedQueryBuilder" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="QueryGroupName" type="string">Default</property>
        <property name="LogAnalyticsViewEvent" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="SelectedPropertiesJson" type="string">["SiteLogo","Path","Title","Description","SecondaryFileExtension","ContentTypeId"]</property>
        <property name="PropertyMappings" type="string" />
        <property name="ShowAdvancedLink" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="NumberOfItems" type="int">10</property>
        <property name="EmitStyleReference" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ShowPreferencesLink" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ServerIncludeScriptsJson" type="string">null</property>
        <property name="IncludeResultTypeConstraint" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Height" type="string" />
        <property name="MaxPagesBeforeCurrent" type="int">4</property>
        <property name="ResultType" type="string" />
        <property name="ShowDidYouMean" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="StartingItemIndex" type="int">1</property>
        <property name="AlwaysRenderOnServer" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="GroupTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Group_Content.js</property>
        <property name="ResultTypeId" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="ItemTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Item_Landingspagina.js</property>
        <property name="AllowConnect" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="HelpUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="ResultsPerPage" type="int">10</property>
        <property name="RenderTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Control_Landingspagina.js</property>
        <property name="AllowEdit" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AllowZoneChange" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AddSEOPropertiesFromSearch" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="AdvancedSearchPageAddress" type="string">advanced.aspx</property>
        <property name="HitHighlightedPropertiesJson" type="string">["Title","Path","Author","SectionNames","SiteDescription"]</property>
        <property name="TitleUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="EmptyMessage" type="string" />
        <property name="ShowBestBets" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ShowViewDuplicates" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="AllowHide" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="BypassResultTypes" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="Description" type="string">Met het webonderdeel Inhoud zoeken kunt u items weergeven die resultaten zijn van een zoekopdracht die u opgeeft. Wanneer u dit webonderdeel aan de pagina toevoegt, worden recent gewijzigde items van de huidige site getoond. U kunt deze instelling veranderen om items van een andere site of lijst weer te geven door het webonderdeel te wijzigen en de zoekcriteria te veranderen.Wanneer de zoekopdracht nieuwe inhoud ontdekt, zal dit webonderdeel telkens wanneer de pagina wordt bekeken een bijgewerkte lijst met items tonen.</property>
        <property name="ShowSortOptions" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ExportMode" type="exportmode">All</property>
        <property name="AllowMinimize" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ShowPersonalFavorites" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ChromeType" type="chrometype">None</property>
        <property name="ShowPaging" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ChromeState" type="chromestate">Normal</property>
        <property name="CatalogIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="HelpMode" type="helpmode">Modeless</property>
        <property name="TitleIconImageUrl" type="string" />
        <property name="ItemBodyTemplateId" type="string" />
        <property name="AlternateErrorMessage" type="string" null="true" />
        <property name="Hidden" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="TargetResultTable" type="string">RelevantResults</property>
        <property name="AllowClose" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="MissingAssembly" type="string">Kan dit webonderdeel niet importeren.</property>
        <property name="ShowResultCount" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ShowLanguageOptions" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ShowUpScopeMessage" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Width" type="string" />
        <property name="RepositionLanguageDropDown" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="Title" type="string">Inhoud zoeken</property>
        <property name="ScrollToTopOnRedraw" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ShowResults" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="ShowAlertMe" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="OverwriteResultPath" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="PreloadedItemTemplateIdsJson" type="string">null</property>
        <property name="MaxPagesAfterCurrent" type="int">1</property>
        <property name="ShowDefinitions" type="bool">False</property>
        <property name="ShouldHideControlWhenEmpty" type="bool">True</property>
        <property name="AvailableSortsJson" type="string">null</property>
        <property name="DataProviderJSON" type="string">{"QueryGroupName":"Default","QueryPropertiesTemplateUrl":"sitesearch://webroot","IgnoreQueryPropertiesTemplateUrl":false,"SourceID":"8413cd39-2156-4e00-b54d-11efd9abdb89","SourceName":"Local SharePoint Results","SourceLevel":"Ssa","CollapseSpecification":"","QueryTemplate":"{searchboxquery} contentclass:\"STS_Site\" ","FallbackSort":[{"p":"ViewsRecent","d":1}],"FallbackSortJson":"[{\"p\":\"ViewsRecent\",\"d\":1}]","RankRules":null,"RankRulesJson":"null","AsynchronousResultRetrieval":false,"SendContentBeforeQuery":true,"BatchClientQuery":true,"FallbackLanguage":-1,"FallbackRankingModelID":"","EnableStemming":true,"EnablePhonetic":false,"EnableNicknames":false,"EnableInterleaving":false,"EnableQueryRules":true,"EnableOrderingHitHighlightedProperty":false,"HitHighlightedMultivaluePropertyLimit":-1,"IgnoreContextualScope":true,"ScopeResultsToCurrentSite":false,"TrimDuplicates":false,"Properties":{"TryCache":true,"Scope":"{Site.URL}","UpdateLinksForCatalogItems":true,"EnableStacking":true,"ListId":"ecf7cef6-a31e-451c-b97a-fc2201bba642","ListItemId":134},"PropertiesJson":"{\"TryCache\":true,\"Scope\":\"{Site.URL}\",\"UpdateLinksForCatalogItems\":true,\"EnableStacking\":true,\"ListId\":\"ecf7cef6-a31e-451c-b97a-fc2201bba642\",\"ListItemId\":134}","ClientType":"ContentSearchRegular","UpdateAjaxNavigate":true,"SummaryLength":180,"DesiredSnippetLength":90,"PersonalizedQuery":false,"FallbackRefinementFilters":null,"IgnoreStaleServerQuery":false,"RenderTemplateId":"DefaultDataProvider","AlternateErrorMessage":null,"Title":""}</property>
        <property name="Direction" type="direction">NotSet</property>
      </properties>
    </data>
  </webPart>
</webParts>
        ]]>
      </AllUsersWebPart>
```

**UPDATE**

I modified the xml. I was talking about this xml with my custom display templates.

Comment: Try check in and check out your display templates and see if its showing any effect..

Answer (score 1):

The solution is to use the "~" character codification, which is:

```
&#126;
```

So instead of:

```
<property name="ItemTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Item_Landingspagina.js</property>
```

use:

```
<property name="ItemTemplateId" type="string">&#126;sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Item_Landingspagina.js</property>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this **item template** `Item_TwoLines.js` to your `item.js`

```
<property name="ItemTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Item_TwoLines.js</property>
```

and for **control template** also replace `Control_ListWithPaging.js` with your `control.js`

```
<property name="RenderTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Control_ListWithPaging.js</property>
```

:)

---

**EDIT**

I think that you write wrong path to files maybe?

```
<property name="ItemTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Item_Landingspagina.js</property>
<property name="RenderTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Control_Landingspagina.js</property>
```

Look where you put your files.

**~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/**

I think that files for display templates must be in

**~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/**

Try with this path

```
<property name="ItemTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Item_Landingspagina.js</property>
<property name="RenderTemplateId" type="string">~sitecollection/_catalogs/masterpage/Display Templates/Content Web Parts/Control_Landingspagina.js</property>
```

Comment: Im sorry, see my update. I was talking about this xml.

Comment: see my update ;)

Comment: no, the path is ok, I provision them to the root folder of the masterpage gallery.